# Why do Mockito.when(mockedService.someMethod(eq("String1")) and Mockito.when(mockedService.someMethod("String1)) behave differently

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, matcher, cglib

In my Test

```java
@Autowired
AnService mockedService();

@TestConfiguration
  static class SpringBootTestConfiguration {
     @Bean
     public AnMockedService mockedService() {
         return mock(AnService.class, withSettings().verboseLogging());
     }
  }

@Test
void anSpringBootTest(){
/* arrange */
.....
when(mockedService.someMethod("String1")).thenReturn(anObject);

/* act */
returnedObject = mockedService.someMethod("String1");
....
```

**returnedObject** is **Null** after the call. If i change the "String1" to eq("String1") something different happens.
Now **returnedObject** is **anObject**

And what I experience too is, that my cache does not get filled but that makes sense when null is returned.

Now the question : *Why do these two variants behave differently?*

Comment: Because without `eq` it does a `==` instead of an `equals`. When comparing `String` you always must use `equals`.

Comment: Thank you  @M.Deinum i just was confused because SonarQube said it doesnt matter.